# Why does the People Picker disappear on an InfoPath Form Web Part when data is loaded?

Tags: web-part, infopath, people-picker

I have an InfoPath form that is accessed through a web part on a SharePoint page.  When viewing the form without any data loaded, the People Pickers are visible.  However, I am using a query string filter to populate the ID field on the form, then use a rule on the form to query for data (based on that ID) which then populates the rest of the form fields.  The problem is that once this data is loaded, the People Pickers just disappear from sight and are never to be heard from again.  Does anyone know why this is happening or how to workaround it?

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was happening for me.  When I did my query I was only querying the Main Data source and did not include the `GetUserProfileByName` data source in my query.